# error in ip2location python library

Tags: python

I am using ip2location Python library to find out location of corresponding ip address.I am trying to open a file containing ip address list and find out corresponding location through that.

```
import IP2Location;

IP2LocObj = IP2Location.IP2Location();
IP2LocObj.open("data/IP-COUNTRY-REGION-CITY-.       LATITUDE-LONGITUDE-ZIPCODE-TIMEZONE-ISP-DOMAIN-NETSPEED-AREACODE-WEATHER-MOBILE-ELEVATION-USAGETYPE-SAMPLE.BIN");//This is sample database
File1=open('test_ip.txt','r');//This is file containing ipaddress
Line=File1.readline();
While line:
    rec = IP2LocObj.get_all(Line);
    Line=File1.readline();
    print rec.country_short
```

This code is giving error.You can check out the sample code here http://www.ip2location.com/developers/python

Comment: could you provide the full error message?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following Python codes.

```
import IP2Location;

IP2LocObj = IP2Location.IP2Location();
IP2LocObj.open("IP-COUNTRY-REGION-CITY-LATITUDE-LONGITUDE-ZIPCODE-TIMEZONE-ISP-DOMAIN-NETSPEED-AREACODE-WEATHER-MOBILE-ELEVATION-USAGETYPE-SAMPLE.BIN"); # This is sample database
with open('test_ip.txt') as f: # file containing ip addresses
    for line_terminated in f:
        line = line_terminated.rstrip('\r\n'); # strip newline
        if line: # non-blank lines
            print line
            rec = IP2LocObj.get_all(line);
            print rec.country_short
```